# convert MM/DD/YYYY to YYYYMMDD in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to convert MM/DD/YYYY to YYYYMMDD in amazon redshift database.

My result of this query gives me some weird result. Can some one please help me.

select to_date ('07/17/2017','YYYYMMDD');

0007-07-20

Answer (score 7):

If you just wish to convert the hard-coded string into a `DATE`:

```
select to_date('07/17/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

If you have a column already formatted as `DATE`, then use:

```
to_char(fieldname, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Combining the two concepts:

```
select to_char(to_date('07/17/2017', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 4):

TO_DATE - converts a date represented in a character string to a DATE data type. 
TO_CHAR - converts a time stamp or numeric expression to a character-string data format.

`select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD');`

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: but this don't work on columns where only time is stored, for an example select to_char('17:00'::time,'HH12:MI AM'), hardcoded works but when column is given in place of 17:00, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE - converts a date represented in a character string to a DATE data type.
TO_CHAR - converts a time stamp or numeric expression to a character-string data format.

select to_date(getdate(),'YYYY-MM-DD') functions it will work

select to_char(getdate(),'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mi:ss')